# Number of optically active compounds among the products of ozonolysis

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, ozone

> The number of optically active compound(s) obtained upon complete ozonolysis of
>   the following optically active compound is
>
> [image: (1E,3R,4Z,6S,7E,10S,11Z,13S)-3,6,10,13-tetramethylcyclotetradeca-1,4,7,11-tetraene]

In the question, I broke all the double bonds and added a $\ce{-CHO}$ group according to the question (ozonolysis).
Checking for the optically active compounds I found two of them:

[image: products]

But the solution has given only one compound! Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 7):

Ozonolysis of the given compound gives $\ce{I}$ , $\ce{II}$ , $\ce{III}$ and $\ce{IV}$.

- $\ce{I}$ and $\ce{II}$ are Homomers and have same configuration "S" and therefore identical (as shown in the figure).
- $\ce{III}$ and $\ce{IV}$ are achiral . Therefore , the total number of optically
  active compounds formed after ozonolysis is $\ce{= 1}$.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The given answer is correct. The product scheme you drew is correct as well. However, as I marked in your scheme (see below), products **A** and **B** are essentially the same enanthiomer (both have (2S)-configuration). The compounds you have drown in right-hand side are also an identical compound, which is not optically active. Therefore, ozonolysis has given only one optically active compound.

[image]